# Do VSS 6 archives open on VSS 2005?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

We have archive of VSS 6 but donot have VSS client.

We have client for VSS 2005. Is it possible to access the VSS archive of v6 from VSS 2005 client?

Answer (score 1):

The format of the database of v6 and v2005 is the same. So it should be fine. You can restore the database archive and access using the new version of VSS client.

Comment: which is newer version? 2005 or v6.0

Comment: 2005 (v8.0) is the newer version.